# Find multiple selector inconsistent odd behavior

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a table that has a `radio` in each row. I want to have a class `selected` for the `tr` which has the `selected radio`.

So I did this:

```
$(":radio[name='grp']").on("change", function() {
    $("#tbl1").find("tr.selected, tr:has(:radio:checked)").toggleClass("selected");
});
```

When you start checking the `radios` from the bottom to the top it works great. However if you start from the top to the bottom, it works once, then it doesn't work once and so on.

I could isolate that without the `find` function the code works great:

```
$(":radio[name='grp2']").on("change", function() {
    $("#tbl2 tr.selected, #tbl2 tr:has(:radio:checked)").toggleClass("selected");
});
```

[Here there is a fiddle for you to test it](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/TRY7s/).

What's happening here?

**Update:** I've also noted that the problem is with the `find` method because when it works it always returns a jQuery object with a length of 2. When it doesn't work, it returns a length of 1. However, if I make the two `find` in separated sentences, they both return a length of 1 and from different elements.

Comment: could you not just to the adding of a class with a click event? Why do you need to do it onchange? Will another js change the radio buttons?

Comment: It doesn't work neither on click event.

Comment: using `input[type=radio]` works perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/kLk6J/.. not sure if that's why `:radio` is listed in the deprecated page http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: @wirey, didn't know it was deprecated.. That's it! The `:radio` selector is working really odd. Please post as an answer.

Comment: @Diego i didn't mean just change the .on('click'), anyway just saw wirey's comment, he has the same plan as me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:radio` has been deprecated as you can see here http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

You should be using `input[type=radio]` to get radio buttons

using `input[type=radio]` works perfectly

http://jsfiddle.net/kLk6J/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do -

```
$(":radio[name='grp']").on("change", function() {
    $("#tbl1").find("tr").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).parents("tr").addClass("selected");
});
```

For each change you remove the selected class from all of the rows and then apply that class to the parent tr of the radio button in question. By toggling you keep turning the class on and off each time you run it, that is not what you want.

Comment: the OP's selector already removes the classes as it toggles them, you do not need to manually remove and add... Its just overkill.

Comment: But it toggles the class for the next radio button as well. This solution works and is rock solid.

Comment: Agree with @JamieHutber, and also if I would do that, at least I would change the first `find("tr")` with `find("tr.selected")`

Answer (score -1):

```
 $("input[name='grp']")

 $("input[name='grp2']")
```

Comment: What does this accomplish? The OP's initial selector is OK.